# Sending a CV::Mat from C++ to python script function

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I am trying to pass a cv::Mat object from C++ code to a python script to have some manipulation on it there (for simplification issue I will just post the code to just display the image).

In the c++ code I did the following:

```
import_array();
Mat image = imread("test.jpg");
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("test");
if (pName == NULL)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    break ;
}
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
if (pModule == NULL)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    break;
}
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "check");
if (pFunc == NULL)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    break;
}
pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
npy_intp dimensions[3] = {image.rows, image.cols, image.channels()};
pValue = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(image.dims + 1, (npy_intp*)&dimensions, NPY_UINT8, image.data);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
if(pResult == NULL)
    LERROR<<"error calling";
```

on the python side

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def check(a):
    image = a
    print (image.shape)
    print (type(image))
    cv2.imshow("win",a)
    return 0
```

shape is printed as (width height channels), type is shown as ndarray but code is crashing on imshow function.

I tried cv2.imread("test.jpg") on the python side and got same results when printing shape and type and imshow did work, so I guess there is something missing when trying to get the data from c++.

Is that the correct way or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the output of `print image.dtype`

Comment: @ZdaR in both cases the output is uint8

Comment: What is the value of "image.dims" in C++?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon image.dims = 2 in c++